# Flow error - The field "Name" isn’t valid for the "Contact" object after Summer 19 preview

Tags: visual-workflow, summer19

I have a flow that calls an Apex method where the following SOQL query is executed:

```
SELECT Id Name FROM Contact WHERE Name LIKE '%%'
```

After the Summer 19' preview was applied in our sandboxes the flow is now failing with the following:

```
The field "Name" isn’t valid for the "Contact" object.
```

I tried recompiling all classes in the sandbox, but that did not take care of the issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: I saw someone mention a similar issue with a condition in Lightning App Builder that referenced contact name -- I'm raising it internally.

Comment: Thanks, I do have a case opened as well.

Comment: Can you give me the case number? I have an email thread I can add it to.

Comment: Thank you - 22836213

Comment: Hi Jay - just wanted to let you know, engineering checked in a fix for this yesterday and it should go out in the next patch (May 28). Bug number is W-6166739.

Answer (score 1):

if your flow calls Apex class, there is similar issue know issue by Salesforce after summer 19 release Please try below work around see if it works. [Link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261799/no-such-column-developername-on-entity-recordtype-after-summer-19-release-o)

Please recompile all classes in org by using compile all classes link on apex classes page under setup or you can do runAllTest in org which will recompile the covered classes. This will fix the issue. We faced a similar issue after Summer 19 release and got it fixed by recompiling all the classes.

Comment: I did come across that before posting this particular one, but it did not work. I thought it was related, but I guess not.