# PersonAssistantName field unavailable to API in Person Account

Tags: rest-api

I have an Org with 'Person account' enable onto it and I am working with Salesforce API to create/update person account record. I am sending some data in 'PersonAssistantName' and getting an error in response stating

> "No such column 'PersonAssistantName' on sObject of type Account".

Though this field does exist in my Org. The same issue is coming on other fields which are related to the person account only, like - 'PersonAssistantPhone', 'PersonHomePhone', etc.

Please assist

Comment: Seems related, try the solution? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261799/no-such-column-developername-on-entity-recordtype-after-summer-19-release-o?r=SearchResults

Comment: @Raul Unfortunately, it is still returning the same error.

Comment: Looks like person account is not enabled properly otherwise mentioned fields will be in account object. Check that first.

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni Everything looks good when I check at the account level or if check these fields from Org. It is just that API is returning this. I think I need to create a case for this.

Comment: Did you try looking up the field on Contact ?

Comment: @altius_rup No, it related to the Account object only.

Comment: Did you see this @Anant ?  https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000093zQIAQ     Maybe you could try looking up the field with dyanmic Apex (eg Database.Query(queryString)) ?

Comment: @altius_rup I don't know if you're able to relate to my query, because solutions are not related. Though thanks for your input.

Comment: @Anant : in that code in the Salesforce Developer forum, the field PersonAssistantName appears in the list of fields lookup up with Describe etc.  Maybe you could lookup up the value of the field with acc.get('PersonAssistantName') instead of acc. PersonAssistantName. Similarly, have you tried Database.Query('SELECT PersonAssistantName FROM Account') ?